# How to get contact number via matching contact name

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to get contact number via contact name I am creating android app in which user just enter contact-name and it automatically fetch the number from contact-list

For example I have 2 text-box contact-name and contact-number when I enter name in contact-name it automatically match name in contact list if match found display its number in contact-number....

how I can do it in ANDROID please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Take name as input in EditText1 and call getb(name,MainActivity.this) on click event. you will get your answer. In android manifest.xml file. add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
enter code here

public String getb(String name, Context context) {
    String ret = null;
    String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" like'%" + name +"%'";
    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            projection, selection, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        ret = c.getString(0);

        editText2.setText(""+ret);
                            }
    c.close();
    if(ret==null)
        ret = "Unsaved";
    return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps: [Contacts-Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html)